# Transpose column data from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` where the head looks like (the actual dataframe is bigger):

```
     Quarter    Body    Total requests  Requests Processed  
  0  Q3 2019       A                93                  92  
  1  Q3 2019       B               228                 210  
  2  Q3 2019       C               180                 178  
  3  Q3 2019       D                31                  31  
  4  Q3 2019       E               555                 483  
  5  Q2 2019       A                50                  50  
  6  Q2 2019       B               191                 177  
  7  Q2 2019       C               186                 185  
  8  Q2 2019       D                35                  35  
  9  Q2 2019       E               344                 297
```

I have another dataframe `df2` which has is currently set up as follows:

```
 Body   Q2 2019 Q3 2019
0   A   
1   B   
2   C   
3   D   
4   E
```

I am trying to find a way to transpose the column `Total requests` from `df1` into `df2` so my desired output looks like:

```
  Body  Q2 2019 Q3 2019
0    A       50      93
1    B      191     228
2    C      186     180
3    D       35      31
4    E      344     555
```

I have had a good look around but can't find without success.

Comment: Try `df.pivot(index='Body', columns='Quarter', values='Total requests')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `unstack` the df1 post setting `Body` and `Quarter` as index , then merge with df2 (if using df2 is important else it works without the merge to):

```
df2.merge(df1.set_index(['Body','Quarter'])['Total requests'].unstack(),
      left_on='Body',right_index=True,how='left',
      suffixes=('_x','')).reindex(df2.columns,axis=1)
```

---

```
  Body  Q2 2019  Q3 2019
0    A       50       93
1    B      191      228
2    C      186      180
3    D       35       31
4    E      344      555
```